# Anchor failed with tab page

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

This is my original screen without full screen, i set the tab control to be anchor

[image]

At the end of my tab page in the tab control unable to anchor to full size when i set it to full screen, the tab page dont have the anchor control

[image]

Comment: Try to add you code, or similar to see where you have the problem. Will be helpfull

Comment: Check the Dock property for your control. Set Anchor for all four side if that helps

Comment: the tab page dont have the dock property and anchor property, the tab control itself got, and i set anchor for the tab control for four side, when i set my application to full screen, the tab control has been maximize but the tab page itself didnt maximize

Comment: @shudy i dont have the code, it is set by property, i am designing my interface before i code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

private void MainInterface_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            PageTab.Refresh();
        }

solved the problem by each time i resizing my main interface, i called the refresh